# LastRow to new LastRow VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that does a `AutoFill` from the `LastRow` to the new `LastRow`.

I have a dataset which contains formulas from column A to AA. When I add a new ID number (in column D) I have to do a `Autofill` manually.

I have used the following code in the past to do a `AutoFill` from the `LastRow` to one row below:

```
Dim sourcerange As Range
Set sourcerange = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 26)
sourcerange.AutoFill Destination:=sourcerange.Resize(rowsize:=2)
```

However it can acure that I add multiple ID numbers. Therefor i need a macro that goes from the `LastRow` (which can be detected in column A) to the (new) `LastRow Offset (1)` in column D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just determine the `NewLastRow` in column D and calculate the `RowSize:=NewLastRow - SourceRange.Row + 1`

```
Dim SourceRange As Range
Set SourceRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 26)

Dim NewLastRow As Long 'get new last row in column D
NewLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=SourceRange.Resize(RowSize:=NewLastRow - SourceRange.Row + 1)
```

---

Please note that you say *"which can be detected in column A"* but …

```
Set SourceRange = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
```

… detects on column 2 which is column B!
If you want the detection on column A instead of B you must use …

```
Set SourceRange = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(1, 26)
```